# How to make the command interpreter aware of the newly created target

Tags: python, debugging, lldb

I want to use LLDB as a python library as described here https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#using-the-lldb-py-module-in-python.

After creating a target with

```py
debugger = lldb.SBDebugger.Create()
target = debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch(path_to_executable, lldb.LLDB_ARCH_DEFAULT)
```

and getting the command interpreter with

```py
interpreter = debugger.GetCommandInterpreter()
```

I try to start the target with

```py
ret = llldb.SBCommandReturnObject()
interpreter.HandleCommand('/r', ret)
```

I get `error: invalid target, create a target using the 'target create' command`. I also tried to set the selected target with `debugger.SetSelectedTarget(target)`, but it didn't work either. Running `file <path_to_target>` in the command handler works as expected.

Is there a way to create a target in python and run commands in the interpreter against it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch` doesn't return valid targets, which you can see by doing `bool(target)`. Use

```py
target = debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch(path_to_executable, lldb.LLDB_ARCH_DEFAULT)
debugger.SetSelectedTarget(target)
```

Comment: If target is not valid, then how `debugger.SetSelectedTarget(target)` could help?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `lldb.LLDB_ARCH_DEFAULT` does not work by some reason on MacOS. So I've replaced it with an explicit name:

```
target = debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch(exe, "x86_64-apple-macosx10.15.0")
```

followed by:

```
assert target
```

which should help to avoid unexpectedly empty target.